# How to get notified after all `aws s3` downloads is complete?

Tags: bash, aws

I am going to run a lot of aws s3 download like so with a bash file

```
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/file0001.txt file0001.txt &
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/file0002.txt file0002.txt &
aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/file0003.txt file0003.txt &
...
```

Of course, as you know, the `&` at the end will make the `aws s3` command to be non-blocking.

Is there a good way so I can get notified when all these non-blocking calls are complete? Does aws offer any mean to monitor overall progress?

Answer (score 0):

If you do *a lot of them* at once you will quickly overload your local box because you will start *a lot of processes* at the same time.

It's better to do one of the following:

- If the files have some common prefix do a recursive copy:

  ```
  aws s3 cp --recursive s3://my-bucket/path/ .
  ```
- Creative use of `aws s3 cp --exclude` and `--include` - i.e. exclude everything except for what's been specified in the include list.

  ```
  aws s3 cp --recursive --exclude '*' \
            --include 'path1/file1.txt' --include 'path2/file2.txt' \
            s3://my-bucket/ .
  ```
- Make use of [s3cmd](https://github.com/s3tools/s3cmd) `--include-from file.txt` which lets you put the required file names into an input file.

  ```
  ~ $ cat include-filenames.txt
  path1/file1.txt
  path2/file2.txt

  ~ $ s3cmd get --recursive --exclude '*' \
                --include-from include-filenames.txt \
                s3://my-bucket/ .
  ```

And no, AWS doesn't provide any way to monitor this - it's running on your local laptop/server, you have to monitor it there.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I can't use it because I only need a subset of files - that's why I have to specify file by file.

Comment: @AnthonyKong you can have the files listed in `--include yourlist.txt` and `--exclude` everything else. Then you can split the list to e.g. 5 equal parts and run 5x `aws s3 cp ...` one with each subset. That way it will run in parallel-serial mode while not spawning loads of processes at once. It generally doesn’t make sense to run more than 5 or 10 parallel downloads from one computer, more than that slows things down again.

Comment: I don't think `--include ` accepts a file with filenames in it. The switch only accepts a file pattern. Cannot get your suggestion in your comment to work.

Comment: @AnthonyKong Added examples for both `aws s3` and `s3cmd`

Answer (score 0):

At the end I wrote a python script to make sure only 10 concurrent s3 download will happen at any given time

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import boto3
from multiprocessing import Pool


BUCKET = "my-bucket"

s3 = boto3.client("s3")


def download_s3_file(params):
    """ If the files exists, assume download is already performed and done
    """
    src, dest = params
    if os.path.exists(dest) and os.path.isfile(dest):
        print(f"The file {dest} is already downloaded ")
        return
    print("Downloading", BUCKET, src, dest)
    print("process id:", os.getpid())
    try:
        s3.download_file(BUCKET, src, dest)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)


def main():
    filelist = sys.argv[1]
    print("parent process:", os.getpid())
    print("Working on ", filelist)
    jobs = []
    for l in open(filelist, "r"):
        # Ignore commented lines
        if not l.startswith("#"):
            src, dest = l.strip().split(",")
            jobs.append((src, dest,))
    with Pool(10) as p:
        p.map(download_s3_file, jobs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```